# IIS restarting ASP.NET website

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, asp.net-core

IIS has to start the application again after I rebuild the website, it takes a very long time and it cuts into productivity.

I am wondering if I can somehow replace the MVC website with a small console application that listens to a port and returns a string that is then interpreted by the browser as valid html. I am not sure if this was done.

Something very lightweight.

So that it does not take 30-50 seconds on each rebuild, to see my site in action.
I want to build my app, then immediately do a request and test it and **not** wait almost a minute.

Is there something that does that?

Comment: Seems you’re not using precompiled sites, or your site is doing something extra on startup. Normally it doesn’t take this long so I’d check those

Comment: You should try to find the root cause for why is it taking too long. Have you tried to rebuild and check a new site? how much time a new site takes?

Comment: You could always use two IIS sites. One for the published version, one for the staging version. Update the staging version, make a request to it in order to bring it up, then swap the host headers so that staging becomes production and production staging. Definitely examine how the current deployment is being done and how it is building the site up. That's an awful long time to deploy so it could be hardware resources are limited, or it's doing something unexpected. The simplest answer though is to choose low volume or standard maintenance windows for deployment

Comment: Browser Link has been a feature in Visual Studio [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/visual-studio/overview/2013/using-browser-link) [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/using-browserlink?view=aspnetcore-2.1) So check that out to improve your productivity.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to build [Self-Hosted Web Api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/hosting-aspnet-web-api/use-owin-to-self-host-web-api) applications.

It can be console exe, or setup to run as a service.

The ASPNET engine, is designed to compile itself (views, etc), but a minute? This might be due to the weak PC, for instance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Browser control in a windows form app. But it is not recommended, there is no way of avoiding IIS restart since your files have been changed.